# Using an R shiny input in an '==' statement

Tags: r, shiny

In R shiny, I am looking to use an input from the user in a statement that uses ==, but the methods that I have tried have all ended in the value returning an NA. Here's an example version of my code so you can see what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
ui <- fluidPage(

  titlePanel("Example Shiny"),

  sidebarLayout(

    sidebarPanel(

      selectInput(inputId = "ID",
                  label = "Choose an ID:",
                  choices = unique(Data$ID)),

    ),

    mainPanel(

      plotOutput(outputId = "distPlot")

    )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output) {

  
  
  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    

#The following statement is what gives me trouble, I am unable to have it give me anything other than an NA from the Data$ID == input$ID

Data.Shiny = Data[Data$ID == input$ID ,]

#There is more code after this which I have tested and works, only the above statement is causing an issue
```

I have tried a variety of solutions, mainly trying to make the input$ID into a different type of variable, like using toString() or as.character(), but neither of these have worked for me. I am still new to shiny coding, and I think that maybe this has to do with making a reactive variable, but I'm no entirely sure.

Any help or suggestions are appreciated!

Thanks

**Edit:**

I was able to fix this by simply making a function outside of shiny code and calling it instead of what I had written before. Basically:

```
to.New.DF <- function(ID){

  Data.Shiny = Data[Data$ID == ID ,]
  return(Data.Shiny)
}

.
.
.

server <- function(input, output) {



  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({



Data.Shiny = to.New.DF(input$ID)
```

Not sure why this works when I tried several similar things with built in R functions, but this solved my problem.

Comment: Where is the `Data` variable being defined?

Comment: It is defined much above this: It is a data frame with lots of variables, but it has a Col with ID numbers in it. I want to make a smaller data frame with only rows that have a specific ID number so that I can use that smaller data frame to produce a graph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(This is posted in the question but I'm reposting so that I can mark as solved)

I was able to fix this by simply making a function outside of shiny code and calling it instead of what I had written before. Basically:

```
to.New.DF <- function(ID){

  Data.Shiny = Data[Data$ID == ID ,]
  return(Data.Shiny)
}

.
.
.

server <- function(input, output) {



  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({



Data.Shiny = to.New.DF(input$ID)
```

Not sure why this works when I tried several similar things with built in R functions, but this solved my problem.